# how to use a variable of type dbms_sql.varchr2_table in where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have added rows from a table into a variable of type dbms_sql.varchar2_table.

```
select id 
  bulk collect into collValyes 
  from tabl1;
```

collValyes  is a variable of type dbms_sql.varchar2_table.
Now i have to use collValyes  in where clause.Like

```
update Table2 
   set Status ='R' 
 where id in collValyes .
```

one xecuting above query , I am getting

```
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

I searched a lot on web but did not find the solutions.
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the FORALL bulk processing for your update:

```
FORALL x IN INDICES OF collValyes
   UPDATE Table2
      SET status = 'R'
    WHERE id = collValyes(x);
```

You can find out more about Oracle FORALL here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm

Hope it helps...